# Do process and threads in the programming libraries or modules mean processes, kernel-level threads, or user-level threads?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

I start to wonder about the difference between processes, kernel-level threads, and user-level threads.

Do process and threads in the Linux API mean processes, kernel-level threads, or user-level threads?

Same question for the standard modules in programming languages such as Python, Java and C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux processes and linux thread obviously will be "kernel level" because Linux *is* the kernel.  But, you should be aware that the distinction between process and thread is not as sharp in Linux as in some other operating systems.  Linux processes and threads are created by the `clone` system call (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), and whether you call the result of clone a "process" or a "thread" depends on what options you give it.

As for language X or library Y, the question of whether threads are "user threads" (a.k.a., "green threads") or "kernel threads" (a.k.a., "native threads") will depend on what language/library you are talking about, and it may depend on what specific version and what specific implementation of the library or language you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks. How can I tell if a library of a language offers "user threads" or "kernel threads"? For example, in Java, or any language that you are familar with?

Comment: @Ben The language specification typically leaves it to the implementation to decide what kind of threads the implementation uses.

Answer (score 0):

First let’s define the terms

User level thread:- a thread which is created and managed by some library outside of kernel. That is kernel is not directly aware of these threads.

Kernel level threads:- created and managed by kernel. For every kernel level thread kernel maintains some data structure to store associated information.

**although these definitions are not universal most of the literature agrees upon them.** ( Operating system concepts, modern operating systems etc)

When we talk about threads created by some library they are always user level threads. **The point to understand is the mapping from user level threads to kernel level threads**.

It’s up to the library (JVM, .NET) that what kind of mapping it uses. It can use one to one model where every user level thread will be mapped to its own kernel level thread. Or it can use many to one model where more than one user threads are mapped to same kernel thread.

As far as Linux is concerned it does not differentiate between process and thread but it provides you the ability to control the level of resource sharing between parent and child. You can do it by using clone system call. if you create a child process with maximum sharing than it’s effectively a thread. On the other hand if you pass flags to clone such that nothing is shared than its a process.

In summary threads in programming libraries are always user level threads. Because they are neither created nor managed (directly) by the kernel.